# Replace part of string if another string exists

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have 3 strings:

```
str1="RHID='1' AND CD_FF='Cartão Crédito'"
str2="CD_FF='Marca/Modelo'"
str3="CD_FF"
```

I need to check if `str3` exists in `str1` and replace `CD_FF='Cartão Crédito'` by `str2`.

I know this can be done with regexp but cannot find a way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with a regex pattern using positive lookbehind with the wanted variable inserted in it:

```
let str1 = "RHID='1' AND CD_FF='Cartão Crédito'";
const str2 = "'Marca/Modelo'";  // no need to hardcode CD_FF here

const variable = "CD_FF";  // can be taken from anywhere

const pattern = new RegExp(`(?<=${variable}=).*`);
str1 = str1.replace(pattern, str2);

console.log(str1);
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> RHID='1' AND CD_FF='Marca/Modelo'
> ```

Note that `str3` is not needed for anything and also that this code correctly does no replacements if the `CD_FF` (or whatever is in `variable`) is not found from the `str1`.

Comment: const variable = obj.dbColumns[i]["db"];
      var  pattern = new RegExp(`${variable}.*`)
      obj.where_str = obj.where_str.replace(pattern, str);

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos This works now exactly as wanted. The problem is on your end. You can verify that the code works by copy-pasting it to your chrome js console.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple string replace would work. If the substring is not found then there would be nothing to replace. No need to check for `CD_FF` first:

```
result = str1.replace("CD_FF='Cartão Crédito'","CD_FF='Marca/Modelo'")
console.log(result)

Output: "RHID='1' AND CD_FF='Marca/Modelo'"
```

Searching for a string that does not exist:

```
wrong = str1.replace("mangoes",str2)
console.log(wrong == str1) 'no change

Output: True
```

Comment: @ruohola how so?

Comment: exactly ruohola . if CD_FF exists

Comment: OP specifically doesn't want the strings to be hard coded.

Comment: @ruohola he didnt specify that. i worked with the data he gave and kept it simple

Answer (score -1):

No regex needed here, since you know the exact values for everything you're searching and replacing.

```
if (str1.includes(str3)) {
  return str1.replace("CD_FF='Cartão Crédito'", str2);
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your other comments, I think you're saying the value of CD_FF can be anything? So then a simple RegEx would work here:

```
if (str1.includes(str3)) {
  return str1.replace(/CD_FF='.*?'/, `CD_FF='${str2}'`);
}
```

In this case, str2 would have just the part you're replacing, not the entire CD_FF string.

Comment: thank you. but i need to replace 'Cartão Crédito' by the value of another variable

Comment: You said "replace CD_FF='Cartão Crédito' by str2." That's what this does. If you want to replace it with something other than the value in str2, please clarify what you actually want to replace it with, and we'll help you from there.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use combination of `includes` and `replace` string methods.

```
let str1 = "RHID='1' AND CD_FF='Cartão Crédito'";
const str2 = "CD_FF='Marca/Modelo'";
const str3 = "CD_FF";

if (str1.includes(str3)) {
    str1 = str1.replace("CD_FF='Cartão Crédito'", str2);
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? Not exactly your code. Notice the `const` for str2 and str3. This one is es6 compliant.